# Loading Values with $zero in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm having some trouble understanding how 'n($zero)' is used in register storage. In the question below, since each hex is 4 bits what value is '6($zero)' which is being loaded into $s1?

```
$s1 = A1B2C3D4
$s2 = 5A6B7C8D

sw $s1, 4($zero)
sw $s2, 8($zero) 
lw $s1, 6($zero)
```

What is the result of $s1 after this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lw $s1, 6($zero)` loads from absolute address `0+6` = 6 and thus faults, unless you're on a modern enough MIPS that unaligned loads are allowed.

If so, the result depends on which endianness mode your MIPS CPU is operating in.  e.g. MARS simulates a little-endian MIPS, where you would get the low half of the store to address `8`, and the high half of the store to `4`.  But it's common for MIPS CPUs to run in big-endian mode.

Comment: It's also common to protect low memory, so even the first `sw` will fault in certain environments.

Comment: @ErikEidt: True, that's why I emphasized absolute address `6` (because that's weird).  But not all setups are like that.  One of MARS's pre-defined memory configs (but not the default one) puts the data section at the very bottom of address space, allowing efficient direct addressing like `myvar($zero)` using just the 16-bit immediate part of MIPS load/store instructions.